# Something wrong with my svn, I cant share project

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

This project has already existed on svn, and I never connected my code to svn before, now I try to update my code with this project on svn, something went wrong [image]

Can somebody help me?
Very Thankful!

Comment: Try `svn cleanup` for your repo. It seems like your previous operation was interrupted incorrectly. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.cleanup.html

Comment: This project was not checked out from svn, so I can't use clean up, it will have 'Path is not a working copy directory' error.

Comment: it's okay I solved the problem

Comment: I convert comment to answer

Answer (score 1):

Try `svn cleanup`(see [doc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.cleanup.html)) for your repo. It seems like your previous operation was interrupted incorrectly.